# Merge different colums of data frames to create new and then a list

Tags: r, list, merge, dataframe

I have two data frames with a global column `ID`.

**df1:**

```
structure(list(ID = c("ILMN_1343291", "ILMN_1343292", "ILMN_1343293", 
"ILMN_1343294", "ILMN_1651209", "ILMN_1651217"), sample1 = c(15.8694849642673, 
11.012283668738, 14.995174021271, 15.5837972369044, 8.08964880277197, 
7.83406791970529), sample2 = c(15.8286939941996, 10.8407625194439, 
14.8818391783215, 15.5951964773238, 8.07397790649028, 7.85669590957356
), sample3 = c(15.8694849642673, 11.453825129904, 14.764465720783, 
15.6917233494908, 8.12884795713027, 7.86320578481668), sample4 = c(15.8694849642673, 
13.1291568945281, 14.8250076629948, 15.7193468523012, 8.07217210194779, 
7.84280084254162), sample5 = c(15.8694849642673, 10.223217362866, 
14.9595743905588, 15.362353159395, 8.12336672246356, 7.80055774746275
), sample6 = c(15.8694849642673, 11.3892037666505, 15.3837334429764, 
15.65923530912, 8.05738048722836, 7.81925084187836)), .Names = c("ID", 
"sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4", "sample5", "sample6"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))
```

**df2:**

```
structure(list(ID = c("ILMN_1343291", "ILMN_1343292", "ILMN_1343293", 
"ILMN_1343294", "ILMN_1651209", "ILMN_1651217"), PVALUE1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4675325), PVALUE2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3290415), 
    PVALUE3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3074713), PVALUE4 = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.3543759), PVALUE5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6465517
    ), PVALUE6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001445087, 0.5390173)), .Names = c("ID", 
"PVALUE1", "PVALUE2", "PVALUE3", "PVALUE4", "PVALUE5", "PVALUE6"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))
```

**Desired output:**

```
  [[1]]
      ID           sample1   PVALUE1
    1 ILMN_1343291 15.869485 0.0000000
    2 ILMN_1343292 11.012284 0.0000000
    3 ILMN_1343293 14.995174 0.0000000
    4 ILMN_1343294 15.583797 0.0000000
    5 ILMN_1651209  8.089649 0.0000000
    6 ILMN_1651217  7.834068 0.4675325
[[2]]
  ID           sample2   PVALUE2
1 ILMN_1343291 15.828694 0.0000000
2 ILMN_1343292 10.840763 0.0000000
3 ILMN_1343293 14.881839 0.0000000
4 ILMN_1343294 15.595196 0.0000000
5 ILMN_1651209  8.073978 0.0000000
6 ILMN_1651217  7.856696 0.3290415

[[3]]
  ID           sample3   PVALUE3
1 ILMN_1343291 15.869485 0.0000000
2 ILMN_1343292 11.453825 0.0000000
3 ILMN_1343293 14.764466 0.0000000
4 ILMN_1343294 15.691723 0.0000000
5 ILMN_1651209  8.128848 0.0000000
6 ILMN_1651217  7.863206 0.3074713

[[4]]
  ID           sample4   PVALUE4
1 ILMN_1343291 15.869485 0.0000000
2 ILMN_1343292 13.129157 0.0000000
3 ILMN_1343293 14.825008 0.0000000
4 ILMN_1343294 15.719347 0.0000000
5 ILMN_1651209  8.072172 0.0000000
6 ILMN_1651217  7.842801 0.3543759

[[5]]
  ID           sample5   PVALUE5
1 ILMN_1343291 15.869485 0.0000000
2 ILMN_1343292 10.223217 0.0000000
3 ILMN_1343293 14.959574 0.0000000
4 ILMN_1343294 15.362353 0.0000000
5 ILMN_1651209  8.123367 0.0000000
6 ILMN_1651217  7.800558 0.6465517

[[6]]
  ID           sample6     PVALUE6
1 ILMN_1343291 15.869485 0.000000000
2 ILMN_1343292 11.389204 0.000000000
3 ILMN_1343293 15.383733 0.000000000
4 ILMN_1343294 15.659235 0.000000000
5 ILMN_1651209  8.057380 0.001445087
6 ILMN_1651217  7.819251 0.539017300
```

I want to merge different columns of `df1` and `df2` and then create a list of all the data frames. I want to merge second column of `df1` and `df2` by `ID` which is first column in both the data frames and store in a list, then merge third column of `df1` and `df2` store in a list, and so on till all columns are done. I know i can use `merge()` to merge two data frame and use `list()` to store in. Here i need to do that in loop. How can in do it with a minimum code otherwise i need to write a long to code to achieve all this. Thanks .

Comment: You want to `merge` or `cbind`? In other words, do both data sets have identicals `ID`s per row?

Comment: Yeah here both have identical `ID`s

Comment: Will `Map(data.frame, Map(cbind, df1[-1], df2[-1]), ID = df1[1])` or `Map(data.frame, ID = df1[1], Map(cbind, df1[-1], df2[-1]))` work for you?

Comment: Seems to be pretty cool except removing the original column names and assigning the column `ID` at last instead of first.

Comment: Need to keep original column names and column `ID` at start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt

```
Res <- Map(function(x, y) cbind(df1[1], x, y), df1[-1], df2[-1])
tempnames <- rbind.data.frame(names(df1)[-1], names(df2)[-1])
Map(function(x, y) `names<-`(x, c("ID", as.character(y))), Res, tempnames)
# $sample1
#             ID   sample1   PVALUE1
# 1 ILMN_1343291 15.869485 0.0000000
# 2 ILMN_1343292 11.012284 0.0000000
# 3 ILMN_1343293 14.995174 0.0000000
# 4 ILMN_1343294 15.583797 0.0000000
# 5 ILMN_1651209  8.089649 0.0000000
# 6 ILMN_1651217  7.834068 0.4675325
# 
# $sample2
#             ID   sample2   PVALUE2
# 1 ILMN_1343291 15.828694 0.0000000
# 2 ILMN_1343292 10.840763 0.0000000
# 3 ILMN_1343293 14.881839 0.0000000
# 4 ILMN_1343294 15.595196 0.0000000
# 5 ILMN_1651209  8.073978 0.0000000
# 6 ILMN_1651217  7.856696 0.3290415
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May i know how it works, and can i use `Map()` with merge in case the `ID` is not identical

Comment: It's just rus `cbind` over corresponding columns, `merge` probably will be more complicated

Comment: What if i have many files and to create list of all the files. The above case consider one file.

Comment: @AaghazHussain I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Above mentioned  data frames `df1` and `df2`, which after combining create a list of many files. Now there is a case where i have many files like `df1` and `df2` and want to create  one list of all the files. `Map()` creates a list combining two files, but i am worried if i can use `list[[length(list)+1]]` to store the files.

Comment: With `lst <- list()` i can easily dump all the files with `lst[[length(lst)+1]]` but `Map()` itself creates a list, how to store a list  as a list with the facility to accommodate other files